# fortran modules' subroutine name conflict

Tags: fortran

I have two different modules each one has the same subroutine. main program will call one of them based on a certain condition. I want to avoid renaming each of these subroutine to a different name.

Comment: You need to post some bare code and have you tried the `USE` statement defining aliases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have two modules `A` and `B` containing the same method `foo()` then first you can create a local alias with

```
program SOModNames
use A, fooA => foo
use B, fooB => foo
implicit none

! Variables
real X(10), Y(10)

call fooA(X,10)
call fooB(Y,10)

end program SOModNames
```

Unofrtunatelty you cannot scope to a module with `call A::foo(X,10)` for example.

Comment: Please answer this question too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134327/fortran-split-mofule-into-multipel-files